# Can I align a bone to face normals?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

[image]

I aligned the bone to the normal of the face as in the gif.
But bone roll is a problem.
I manually approximated to set the value of roll but it is not numerically correct.
Do you know a good way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the face and create a new orientation coordinate system clicking the plus button. Then set cursor to selected, then select the head of the bone and set selection to cursor, then do the same with its tail ( so both are in the same spot) then (still with only tail selected) press G Z, move the mouse and confirm LMB.

This procedure will automatically set the roll.

[image]

Comment: Amazing trick !! It works perfectly.
But can you explain a bit more about how the custom transform orientation will automatically align the rolls of bone?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the code so deeply, I just noticed that a bone gets its starting roll in relationship with the locations of its head and tail.

Comment: How would we go about setting the roll of a bone that's running perpendicular to a surface?